# Return a list of rows since a specified date 

Tags: sql-server

How would I return a list of rows since a date I specify in SQL Server, here is what I currently have:

```
select * from SALESTABLE where CREATEDDATETIME 
BETWEEN '26/04/2012 00:00:00.00' AND GETDATE()
```

But this throws an error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type 
>   resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: between '26 April 2012' and getdate()

Comment: That worked! Could you put it as an answer so I can accept, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BETWEEN '26 April 2012' AND GETDATE()
```

that'll work

Answer (score 1):

Change your string format:

```
select * from SALESTABLE where CREATEDDATETIME 
BETWEEN '20120426' AND GETDATE()
```

Edit: Updated from comments, never knew dashes broke the ISO format - I'd always assumed that was 'normal' since SQL management studio outputs dates in that format

Comment: You should use the `YYYYMMDD` format (**no** dashes!) - since only that is truly "universal" and will work with any language setting. Your code will break with various language settings...

Comment: The DATETIME in SQL Server doesn't have any format - it's a 8-byte binary. The "format" is for display (and parsing) only.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from SALESTABLE where CREATEDDATETIME 
BETWEEN '26/04/2012 00:00:00.00' AND GETDATE()
```

change this to

```
select * from SALESTABLE where CREATEDDATETIME 
BETWEEN CONVERT(datetime, '26/04/2012', 103)  AND GETDATE()
```

and see if it helps

Comment: to_date is not a recognised function name, I'm using MSSQL